# Hadamard regularization boundary condition

Tags: quantum-field-theory, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I am working through the Hadamard regularization of two-point functions of scalar fields in curved spacetime in 2D e.g. equations 26 and 33-36 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0512118v2.pdf.

The idea is to impose upon two-point functions of the Klein-Gordan equation,

$$(\Box_x + m^2 + \xi R)G(x,x') = 0,$$
the "Hadamard form",

$$G = \frac{1}{4\pi}\left( V(x, x') \ln\sigma + W(x, x') \right) $$

where $V(x, x')$ and $W(x, x')$ are both regular and $\sigma$ is half the square geodesic distance between $x$ and $x'$. Due to the regularity assumptions upon them $V$ and $W$ can be expanded:

$$V(x, x') = \sum_{n=0} V_n(x, x') \sigma^n  $$
$$W(x, x') = \sum_{n=0} W_n(x, x') \sigma^n  $$

which results in a set of recurrence relations for $V_n$ and $W_n$, and a boundary condition on $V_0$. In 2D the boundary condition is

$$ V_0^{;\mu} \sigma_{;\mu} = V_0 \frac{\Delta^{1/2}_{;\mu}}{\Delta^{1/2}} \sigma^\mu$$

where the $;$ mean covariant differentiation and $\Delta$, another two-point function, happens to be called the "van Vleck-Morette determinant". Even without knowing anything else about $\Delta$, the solution to this PDE can be seen by inspection to be

$$ V_0 = a \Delta^{1/2}$$

but the aforementioned reference specifically asserts

$$V_0 = -\Delta^{1/2}$$

without comment.This is equivalent to the demand that

$$\lim_{x' \to x} V_0 = -1$$

where the limit is along a geodesic, but I'm having trouble seeing why this should be. Where does the $-1$ come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*A priori* one can fix that limit  arbitrarily and this is an "initial condition" for the definition of $G$ which, with your hypotheses, is defined up to a constant factor.

There is another requirement I do not remember if the author impose (we have had some discussions when they wrote that paper, in fact my name appears in the acknowledgements:)).

One has to demand  that $G(x,y)-G(y,x)$ coincides (up to a factor $\pm i$ depending on conventions) to the **causal propagator**, which is independently defined.  I do not remember the form of it in 2D spacetimes (it is  the difference of the advanced and the retarded fundamental solutions), but this requirement fixes that limit.

Another possibility to fix that value is requiring that $G(x,y)$  coincides to the two-point function of 2D Minkowski vacuum if the spacetime is Minkowski one. General local covariance imposes that the value do not depend on the spacetime.

Comment: Hi again! Is it reasonable to argue that the ambiguity in this constant is degenerate with the ambiguity with the renormalization mass? I.e. the constant one needs to put inside the logarithm to make its argument dimensionless, which I implicitly set to $1$ above. $-1$ could then be fixed in flat spacetime by the expectation that the renormalization mass is $1$, and by comparison with existing theory as you mention.

The reason behind this is basically that I'm using the opposite signature convention as the reference. So I'm a bit confused about whether I should use +1 instead of -1.

Comment: If you impose that the antisymmetric part of $G$ coincides with the causal propagator the mass scale you insert in the logarithm does not matter because the two contributions cancel each other. However, notice that there is an $\epsilon$ prescription inside $\sigma$ and it plays a crucial role in the argument a pointed out.